# What are the difference between these media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

What are the difference between these:

```
@media (max-width: 100px) { /* CSS Rules */ }

@media screen (max-width: 100px) { /* CSS Rules */ }

@media screen and (max-width: 100px) { /* CSS Rules */ }

@media only screen and (max-width: 100px) { /* CSS Rules */ }

@media only screen (max-width: 100px) { /* CSS Rules */ }
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: Did you try searching first? mdn has a full document explaining this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between these examples is the syntax.

`@media (max-width: 100px) { /* CSS Rules */ }` - this is a basic media query that checks the maximum width of the screen. Since no media type is specified it defaults to `screen`.

`@media screen (max-width: 100px) { /* CSS Rules */ }` - this media query is similar to the first one, but it explicitly specifies the media type as `screen`.

`@media screen and (max-width: 100px) { /* CSS Rules */ }` - this is the same as the second example - the `and` is implied in the prior case but explicitly set here.

`@media only screen and (max-width: 100px) { /* CSS Rules */ }` - this media query is the most specific and recommended syntax. It uses the `only` keyword to hide the media query from older, incompatible browsers, and it explicitly specifies the media type as `screen`.

`@media only screen (max-width: 100px) { /* CSS Rules */ }` - this is similar to the fourth example, but it does not use the `and` keyword explicitly.

Comment: Wow, thank you so so much! You've helped me understand this SOO much. Have a wonderful, beautiful Sunday! :)

Comment: You are very welcome and the same to you :)